# Hovering makes elements appear over each other

Tags: html, css, hover, position, css-position

Here is a (Dutch) control panel I was working on. When you hover over CV or geen afspraak, relevant content is shown. Only problem: when you hover over CV, geen afspraak appears over the other text, making it partly unreadable. Anybody know how to solve this puzzle?

(In order to make certain objects appear the right way when hovering, I gave them position:absolute or the relative, depending on its goal. That may cause the problem but I don't know how to solve it.)

```css
.control_panel {
  background-image: url(https://image.freepik.com/vrije-psd/witte-houtstructuur-achtergrond-ontwerp_1022-75.jpg);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.witte_achtergrond {
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.acsuel-dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#broer:hover .acsuel-dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.geen_afspraak {
  position: relative;
}

#broer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#broer {
  position: relative;
}

.hoer:hover .veeltekst {
  display: block;
}

#saaf {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: -220px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.hoer {
  position: relative;
}

.veeltekst {
  text-overflow: none;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  display: none;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="control_panel">
  <div class="witte_achtergrond">Verklaring Omtrent het Gedrag</div>
  <div class="hoer">
    <div class="witte_achtergrond hover">CV</div>
    <p class="veeltekst">De afgelopen vijf jaar ben ik gepromoveerd op natuurwetenschappen, toen ben ik me nog meer gaan focussen op mijn werk als regisseur. Ik heb een zoon gekregen en heb verschillende bijbanen gehad in de filmwereld.<br><br> Creatief en enthousiast</p>
  </div>
  <div id="broer">
    <div class="witte_achtergrond geen_afspraak hover">
      geen afspraak
    </div>
    <div class="acsuel-dropdown">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="wk">wk</th>
            <th>ma</th>
            <th>di</th>
            <th>wo</th>
            <th>do</th>
            <th>vr</th>
            <th class="weekend">za</th>
            <th class="weekend">zo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="wk">13 </td>
            <td class="sq" class="previous" data-d ate="2018-03-26">26</td>
            <td class="previous" data-date="2018-03-27">27</td>
            <td class="previous" data-date="2018-03-28">28</td>
            <td class="previous" data-date="2018-03-29">29</td>
            <td class="previous" data-date="2018-03-30">30</td>
            <td class="previous weekend" data-date="2018-03-31">31</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-01">1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wk">14 </td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-02">2</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-03">3</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-04">4</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-05">5</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-06">6</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-07">7</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-08">8</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wk">15 </td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-09">9</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-10">10</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-11">11</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-12">12</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-13">13</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-14">14</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-15">15</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wk">16 </td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-16">16</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-17">17</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-18">18</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-19">19</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-20">20</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-21">21</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-22">22</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wk">17 </td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-23">23</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-24">24</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-25">25</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-26">26</td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-27">27</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-28">28</td>
            <td class="weekend" data-date="2018-04-29">29</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wk">18 </td>
            <td data-date="2018-04-30">30</td>
            <td class="next" data-date="2018-05-01">1</td>
            <td class="next" data-date="2018-05-02">2</td>
            <td class="next" data-date="2018-05-03">3</td>
            <td class="next" data-date="2018-05-04">4</td>
            <td class="weekend next" data-date="2018-05-05">5</td>
            <td class="weekend next" data-date="2018-05-06">6</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That depends on what you want. You could set a solid background color for the `veeltekst` content, remove its `position:absolute` etc.

Comment: @MrLister it worked! removing position:absolute from veeltekst. thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem using [Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister)s advise to remove `position:absolute` from `veeltekst`.

Comment: Since you have already fixed it using the above comments. Please mark your answer as correct.